# Problem in finding the Euclidean measure of a set in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, path-connected

> **Problem.** For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, let $S_{\alpha}=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3~|~ x^2+y^2+z^2=\alpha^2\}$.
>
> Let $E=\bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R\setminus \mathbb{Q}}}S_\alpha$. Which of the followings are true?
>
> 1. The Lebesgue measure of $E$ is infinite?
> 2. E contains an nonempty open set.
> 3. E is path-connected .
> 4. Every open set containing $E^c$ has infinite Lebesgue measure.

**My Solution.**

1. **True**. Since $E^c=\bigcup_{\alpha\in  \mathbb{Q}}S_\alpha$ and $\mu(S_\alpha)=0$ So by countable additivity of $\mu$, $E^c$ has measure zero.
2. **False**. Since $E$ and $E^c$ both are Dense in $\mathbb{R^3}$.
3. **False**. Since any two sphere of irrational radius always there exists an intermediate sphere of rational radius between them.
4. **True**. I think there is only one open set containing $E^c$ namely $\mathbb{R^3}$. And $\mu(\mathbb{R^3})=\infty.$

But the answer key indicates the options: 1 is only **True**.
Then what is wrong with my conclusion about option 4. Please let me know where I made mistake. Thank You..

Comment: The open set only needs to contain a countable collection of the $S_\alpha$. Each 'shell' can be contained in an open set of arbitrarily small measure. Sum them up. Basically the same way you would show that the rationals have measure zero in the reals.

Comment: Oho ... u r right....!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, we know $E^c = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} S_{\alpha}$. Let $(a_n)_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define:
$$
r_n = \min \left\{ \frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{{a_n}^4 2^n}  \right\}
$$
where $r_n = 1/2^n$ if $a_n = 0$, and
$$
R_n = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, {a_n}^2 - r_n < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < {a_n}^2 + r_n \}
$$
Remark that each $R_n$ is open, and that the size of $R_n$ is given by the difference of two spheres, i.e.:
\begin{align*}
\mu(R_n) &= \mu(B(0,{a_n}^2+r_n)) - \mu(B({a_n}^2-r_n))
\\ &= \frac{4}{3} \pi ({a_n}^2 + r_n)^3 - \frac{4}{3} \pi ({a_n}^2 - r_n)^3
\\ &= \frac{4}{3} \pi  \left( 6 {a_n}^4 r_n + 2 {r_n}^3   \right)
\\ &\leq \frac{4}{3} \pi \left( \frac{6}{2^n} + \frac{2}{2^{3n}}  \right)
\\ &\leq \frac{48 \pi}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align*}

Since each $R_n$ is open, their union is open. It is also clear that the union of the $R_n$ contains $E^c$, and finally we have:
$$
\mu \left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} R_n \right)
\leq
\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{48 \pi}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}
= \frac{48 \pi}{3}
$$
This gives an example of an open set that contains $E^c$ which has finite measure.